# Traslation of a bar on a plane - Contrasting results

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, torque, education

I have a bar which can translate on a plane (gravity along y), at estremity A there are two forces and a moment, G is the center of mass, here I applied the gravity force:

[image]

The dynamic equations are:

$$ F_x = m \, a_x $$
$$ F_y -m \, g = m \, a_x $$

The problem is the rotational equation; the angular acceleration is null because the bar can only translate. If I write the equation with respect to the point A, I get:

$$ M=0 $$

instead if I choose G:

$$ M-b \, F_x=0 $$

Why?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> the angular acceleration is null because the bar can only translate.
>   If the bar can only translate, if teams that there is some external factor that prevents it from rotating. Thus, any moment will be 0, because the bar is held firmly on its axis.

It does not matter if you choose the point A or G in order to calculate the moment, as it will still be 0, because the bar is not allowed to rotate.

If the bar COULD rotate, then you should not take point A as your reference points, as that is the point to which you are applying the torques, and torques are $$\tau = Fdcos(\theta)$$but in this case, you are applying a force on that very point, so d would be 0, and so is your torque. It is like trying to open a door by pushing on its pivots rather than its handle. You have to always look for the simplest possible point, which in this case seems to be the center of the bar, G.

Comment: Hello @NickHeumann the torque is along an axis for definition, it is not applyed at a point.

Comment: I don't quite understand which you mean. Are you saying that the moment M is making the bar spin "vertically", on its own axis?

Comment: I mean that the moment does not have an application point as the forces. If I draw the moment M at the opposite extremity of the bar, the situation is the same.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. In that case, the moment M should not be in the same equation as the torque applied  by Fx, because the Fx makes the bar spin either clockwise or counterclockwise, but M makes it spin on itself, which is a different space than Fx, and they should not be together. M should cause a constant spin that depends on the bar's inertia, and only the resulting angular momentum would cause problems. However, that seems like a much more complicated problem, so I might be wrong here